# how to deploy springboot and camel application in tomcat as war file and execute

Tags: tomcat, deployment, apache-camel

I have a springboot camel application for consuming data sources.

The application is working correctly in embedded tomcat server, but now what i want is deploy this application to a standalone tomcat server.

Not finding any sources for this, but i do find answers for war deployment to external tomcat only.
The application is not a web based so no need to check in browser but it should work so that internally it can consume date thorough camel integrated with springboot.

Your help will be appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understand your question, but to build a WAR file from a SpringBoot application, you have to take some small extra steps that are [described in this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy) or in the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

If the WAR is built you can simply drop it into tomcats `webapps` folder. Tomcat has by default auto-deployment enabled and therefore should extract the WAR file into a folder and start the application. See also [here for Tomcat deployments](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).